# Possible To Make Google Drive Folder Permanently On My Computer, Even If Owner Deletes?

Tags: google-drive

I'm wondering if it's possible to make sure the contents of a Google Drive folder will stay in my drive, even if the owner deletes/restricts access.

I guess I could download everything inside, but is there a way I can just keep everything so that even if he removes, I can still access?

Thanks

Comment: You can use third-party software to mount it like a network drive

Comment: Do you have the Google Drive desktop application installed?

Comment: Yeah, I have the desktop software installed, and everything is synced, but I think, if the owner of a file/folder revokes access online or in HIS local folder, I lose access, right?